# make function which returns the title of data structure

Tags: haskell

There are several data types.

```
data Book =BName| Author deriving (Eq,Show)
data Video = VName deriving (Eq,Show)
data CD =Cname | Auth | NOC deriving (Eq,Show)
data Product = Product Book Video CD deriving (Eq,Show)
```

make function getTitle which return the name(BName,CName or VName) of structure.
For example
 getTitle (Book "name "noname") -> "name"
 getTitle (Vide "name") -> "name"
 and etc.

Is it possible?

Exist data type Book with fields title and author,Videocassete with field author, CDdisk with fields title,number of compositions and author.
1)create data type Product which can introduce this data types
2)make function getTitle which returns titles.
3)make function getTitles which returns all titles in the list of products(use function getTtitle)
4)make function bookAuthors which return books' authors in the list of products
5)make function lookupTitle::String->[Product]->Maybe Product which returns product with input name
6)make function lookupTitles::[String]->[Product]->[Product] which input params are the list of names and the list of products and for every name it gets products from list of products. Ignor names in the first list without products in the second list for them.Use function lookipTitle.

That's all task.

---

```
data Book = Book String String deriving(Eq,Show)
data Video = Video String deriving(Eq,Show)
data CDisk = CDisk String String Int deriving(Eq,Show)
--titles
class Titleable a where
 getTitle :: a ->String
instance Titleable Book where
 getTitle (Book title _) = title
instance Titleable Video where
 getTitle (Video title) = title
instance Titleable CDisk where
 getTitle(CDisk title _ _) = title
--get titles
getTitles (x:xs) = [ getTitle x | x<-xs ]
lookupTitle _ [] =Nothing
lookupTitle::String->[Product]->Maybe Product
lookupTitle a (x:xs)  | getTitle x==a =Just x
                             | otherwise = lookupTitle a (x:xs)
lookupTitles::[String]->[Product]->[Product]
lookupTitles (x:xs) (y:ys) = [y|x<-xs,y<-ys,x==lookupTitle y]
```

but
1)I don't know how to make function bookAuthors(how can function find that the parameter is book-type?)
2)how to make Product type?I mean it is either Book or Video or CDisk
3)lookupTitle and lookupTitle are correct?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. For example, `Book "name" "noname"` is not even a valid expression.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you sure you want the data types like this?

```
data Book = BName | Author deriving (Eq,Show)
```

Means a Book is either a BName (book name?) or an Author?

I suspect you want something similar to

```
data Book = Book BName Author
```

e.g. a book has a book name and an author

If you want to capture the essence of "titleable" things you could use type classes.

```
class Titleable a where
  getTitle :: a -> String

instance Titleable Book  where
  getTitle (Book title _) = title
```

And write instances for your other types.

Comment: for such code
`code` data Book = Book BName Author
data Video = Video Tit
data CDisk = Cname Auth Noc
data Product = Book | Video | CDisk deriving (Eq,Show)
`code`
errro - undefined type constructot Noc

Comment: You need to define what "Noc" is

Comment: But it number of compositions on CDisk. How I can define it?
It's one of the fields of CDisk.

Comment: Could you have a go at editing your question to define the problems in a bit more detail?

Comment: `lookupTitle _ [] = Nothing
lookupTitle x (y:ys) | getTitle y==x = Just y
                              |otherwise = lookupTitle x ys

lookupTitles xs ys = [lookupTitle x ys |x<-xs]`
It was working yesterday but it doesn't work today

Answer (score 0):

From the task description, it sounds like the data type they are looking for is something like this:

```
type Title = String
type Author = String

data Product = Book Title Author
             | Video Title
             | CD Title Integer Author
             deriving (Eq, Show)
```

The function `getTitle` can then be implemented using pattern matching.

```
getTitle (Book title _) = title
getTitle (Video title)  = title
getTitle (CD title _ _) = title
```

I'll leave the implementation of the remaining functions to you.

Comment: It does. The type of `getTitle` here is `Product -> Title`. `Book`, `Video` and `CD` are _data constructors_ of the `Product` type, and not types themselves.

Comment: I've already understood it.
Why for such code
`getTitles (x:xs) = [ getTitle x | x<-xs ]`
where
`let a= Book "name" "tname"
let b=Video "role"
let c=CD "play" 5 "rrr"
let g=[a,b,c]`
getTitles g return only ["role","play"]

Comment: That's because when you pattern match `[a, b, c]` against the pattern `(x:xs)`, you get `x = a` and `xs = [b, c]`. You want `getTitles xs = ...` instead so that you get the whole list in `xs`.

Comment: And the last question because other fucntions works normal. How to return only authors of the books?

Comment: You can do that using pattern matching in a list comprehension: `[author | Book _ author <- products]`. This will skip the elements of the list which do not match the pattern.